# is there a class history visualization tool for SVN

Tags: svn, version-control, visualization

I know of [codeswarm](http://code.google.com/p/codeswarm/) and [gource](http://code.google.com/p/gource/), but AFAIK they visualize the repository on a class level.
 What i would like to see **animated** is the history of a single file (or a package) - LOC count is essential, LOComment, dependencies, method count a.s.o. would sure be nice too :)

Answer (score 2):

It isn't animation, but if you want to see a single file's history "all at once" [Ned Batchelder's svn blameall](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/utilities/blameall_py.html) is a useful tool, and probably gets the same sort of thing across in a static presentation.  (It would probably be a good starting point, if you have any idea what you'd want the animation to look like - blameall takes care of the svn mechanics well enough, and is written in Python.)

Comment: Thank you, eichin. blameall surely is a nice tool. It is a little too fine-grained though (which is not a problem if you can change the resolution, but with blameall you can only change the scope AFAIK) and unfortunately as far from animated as a console output goes. Codeswarm just captivated me with its cool birds-eye view of our work of the last months and it was quite rewarding too. Thats what i'm seeking for - less for production (if it proves useful, then definitely for production too), more like a campfire to gather round and gaze.

Answer (score 0):

Not an animation either, but probably a very useful tool to find history of a method: http://codicesoftware.blogspot.com/2011/01/method-history-for-subversion-is-here.html

Comment: I'm afrad i must wait a little longer still as the tool is only available for C# ATM. Thanks, pablo